# Is there a way for MVC Partial View retrieved using jQuery to keep UI CSS Styling?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have an MVC 2 project, consisting of a MasterPageView a child View called Index and a number of PartialViews. The PartialViews are loaded into the Index View using the jQuery Ajax method $.get(....).

My problem is that I am styling the buttons using jQuery UI like:

```
$('button').button();
```

but I find that I need to do this on every PartialView. What I would like to do is define
this once in the MasterPageView, but if I do this the styling is lost. I'm guessing this 
is because the styling is applied before the DOM is loaded, is this correct? Is there any
way to implement this i.e. just define it on the MasterPageView?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Is there a reason you need to style them using jQuery? Why not just have a CSS selector that styles all the buttons?

Answer (score 2):

This wont work when objects are added to the DOM after the initial load.  In those cases you should go for the new .live() syntax in jQuery :

```
$("button").live("load", function(){
    $(this).button();
});
```

It listens for new objects being added to the DOM and attaches an eventhandler to it..

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Yngve, thanks for the reply. I tried this but it didn't work. I placed this in the MasterViewPage but when I loaded my PartialView there was no styling.